# Buffs on minions with echo

Tags: hearthstone

In [Dalaran Heist](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/The_Dalaran_Heist), suppose I buff a minion with [Echo](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Echo) in Bob's Tavern.  For example, suppose I use [Tell a Story](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Tell_a_Story) to give the minion +2/+2 for this run.  If I play multiple copies of that minion in a single turn (using its Echo ability), do all of the copies receive the buff, or only the first copy?

Answer (score 2):

All copies receive the buff.

If you modify the mana cost of the minion, the modification affects only the first copy of the minion, but subsequent copies have the base minion cost.